# Mysql Left Join Query not displaying correct values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables `person` and `courses_by_instructors`.  I am executing an sql query but I am not getting the desired result. I am trying to pull from `person` table all those with `instructor_roles = 1` then I am trying to show the instructors who are teaching course: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d4f9/3)

person

```
+------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+------------+
| company_id | person_id |  person_name   | instructor_role | staff_role |
+------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+------------+
|          1 |       154 | James Newton   |               1 |          0 |
|          2 |       154 | James Newton   |               1 |          0 |
|          5 |       478 | Tina Turner    |               1 |          1 |
|          4 |       258 | James Fuller   |               1 |          0 |
|          5 |       714 | Michael Jordan |               1 |          0 |
|          6 |       714 | Michael Jordan |               1 |          0 |
|          7 |       964 | Steve Johnson  |               1 |          0 |
|          7 |       687 | Fred Willis    |               0 |          1 |
+------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+------------+
```

courses_by_instructors

```
+--------+------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| cbi_id | company_id |  course_name   | course_id |  person_name   | person_id |
+--------+------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
|  1     |          1 | Business Logic |         1 | James Newton   |       154 |
|  2     |          5 | Emerging Tech  |        15 | Michael Jordan |       714 |
|  3     |          1 | Research       |        10 | James Newton   |       154 |
|  4     |          5 | Economics      |         9 | Tina Turner    |       478 |
+--------+------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
```

1. Pull everyone with `instructor_role = 1`
2. Then show all instructors but also indicate if they are in the `courses_by_instructor` table by showing their `cbi_id`. Not all of them are in that table.

Current Result for `company_id = 5`

```
+-----------------+--------+
| instructor_name | cbi_id |
+-----------------+--------+
| James Newton    |   null |
| Tina Turner     |      4 |
| Michael Jordan  |      2 |
+-----------------+--------+
```

Desired Result for `company_id = 5`

```
+-----------------+--------+---------------+
| instructor_name | cbi_id | course_name   |
+-----------------+--------+---------------+
| James Newton    |        |               |
| James Newton    |        |               |
| Tina Turner     |      4 | Economics     |
| James Fuller    |        |               |
| Michael Jordan  |      2 | Emerging Tech |
| Michael Jordan  |        |               |
| Steve Johnson   |        |               |
| Fred Willis     |        |               |
+-----------------+--------+---------------+
```

SQL Query

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.person_name, p.instructor_role, IFNULL(lj.company_id, 0) as  company_id, lj.person_id, lj.cbi_id
FROM person as p
LEFT JOIN courses_by_instructors as lj
      ON (lj.person_id = p.person_id AND lj.company_id = 5)
WHERE instructor_role = 1
GROUP BY cbi_id
ORDER BY person_name
```

Comment: is this a homework or is it really being used commercially? for commercial use these tables dont seem good enough. lots of data redundancy. should normalize it someday...

Comment: Randoms what if you remove group by cbi_id??

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille, great idea! I almost got it to work, it is showing duplicate values when doing something like `company_id = 7`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00bbb/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its kind of hard understanding what you want with the part about

```
 company_id=5
```

But I think this should work... if not let me know what needs to be changed:

```
SELECT 
p.person_name as "Instructor Name",
c.cbi_id,  as "C.B.I. I.D.",
c.course_name "Course Name"
FROM 
person as p
LEFT JOIN courses_by_instructors as c ON c.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE p.instructor_role = 1
GROUP BY p.person_id
ORDER BY p.person_name
```